# Different 'development' environments for different developers

Tags: environment-variables, development-environment, environment

We have three environments: development, staging, and production.

In our configuration variables for development, we set our database to connect to 127.0.0.1 with a set username or password.

However, other developers part of our team have different username and password configurations.

How do we reconcile this without making development_steve, development_mark, development_amir, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually we decided to use the same local credentials for our DBs.